# Parse : Facebook login and localDataStore

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I ran into some strange behaviour while implementing the facebook login from Parse.com in my application. Here's how to replicate it with the Blank Facebook App sample code from their samples:

I want to create a new "Post" associated to the current user. At the end of the onCreate() from UserDetailsActivity, I added :

```
ParseObject post = new ParseObject("Post");
post.put("name", "New post");
post.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }           
});
```

This work pretty well until I enable the localDataStore in the Application. The code above returns :

```
com.parse.ParseException : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Cannot save a ParseUser until it has been signed up. Call signUp first.
```

Note : the data associated with the ParseUser returned in the callback of ParseFacebookUtils.logIn() are null (objectId, username, ..) which explains the behaviour above.

The question is then : why adding

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
```

to the App makes facebook login return an empty ParseUser ?

Ths error happens once every two launches :

- First launch, no valid current user is stored in the offlineStore database, facebook login successfully add one, everything works perfectly
- Second launch, a valid user is already stored, which is replaced by an "OfflineObject" User with no objectId or data, causing the error above.

I'm using Parse 1.5.0 & Facebook SDK 3.14.

Comment: I think there is no solution yet and your issue is related to this: https://www.parse.com/questions/android-local-datastore-getcurrentuser

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` is returning null as per [https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#getCurrentUser()](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#getCurrentUser%28%29). You may want to do a facebook login first and then try to use the ParseUser

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(getActivity(), new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
        if(user != null) {
            // use ParseUser here
        }
    }
});
```

Also, I wouldn't recommend using Parse 1.5.0 with version 3.14 of the facebook SDK. The docs for Parse https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers state that "Parse is compatible with v3.0 of the Facebook SDK for Android." My experience leads me to believe they aren't lying.